# Can I use http(s) to download safari bookmarks from icloud?

Tags: safari, icloud, bookmarks

Safari bookmarks are synchronized into icloud if you request it in iOS. But I can't see a way to download them from there.

I have an iphone but a Windows or Linux laptop. I don't use Safari on my laptops. I'd like to be able to pull my bookmarks (or ideally my history) from safari on my iphone to my laptop. I don't need to import it directly into a browser. I'd rather just make an app to present the data.

I presume that somewhere, somehow, there is a url that I could just retrieve (with the necessary authentication of course) and it would be the XBEL (or whatever format it is these days) of my bookmarks.

I guess another option is for me to switch to a different browser on my iphone that does allow me access to the bookmarks and history from inside icloud?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I am investigating something similar and could use some help as well.

Comment: Nope. :-(

Microsoft Phone app is coming but still doesn't work for iphone.... someone on the team on twitter told me they were still working on it tho.